# Executing PySpark on Snowflake after successfully import pyspark as a wheel

Tags: pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created a wheel file from a PySpark download from PyPi.

I have successfully imported the wheel into Snowflake.

I would like to execute the following simple PySpark code. You will notice code such as spark.sql in the code - this is typical PySpark/SparkSQL syntax.

When execute the PySpark code below I get the following error:

[image]

The pyspark code is as follows:

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
import wheel_loader
def checkTableExists(tableName,stageName="base"): 
    wheel_loader.load('pyspark-3.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl')
    
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
    try:
        spark.sql(f"describe {stageName}{tableName}")
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        return False
def main(session: snowpark.Session):
    return checkTableExists('test', 'TEST')
```

Can someone let me know why I'm getting the error? My guess is because, I've either incorrectly created the pyspark.whl, which incidently is 'pyspark-3.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl'. Or snowflake needs me to import more modules?

Any thoughts

I installed py4j as suggested by @Sergiu

[image]

But now I get a a whole of errors:

[image]

Comment: That happens because PySpark uses Py4J, which is a framework that facilitates interoperation between the Python and Java languages, to exchange data between the Python and the JVM processes. When you launch a PySpark job, it starts as a Python process, which then spawns a JVM instance and runs some PySpark specific code in it. You can only import pure Python packages in Snowflake.

Comment: Hi @Sergiu, thanks for reaching out. So, what is the solution?

Comment: Hi @Sergiu, I have updated the question after your suggestion regarding Py4J, but now I'm getting a whole bunch of errors. This leads me to think the .whl file is corrupt. What do you think?

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding, Py4J launches a Java process and Python code on Snowflake runs on a sandbox-ed environment which means you won't be able to spin up any JVM. What are the reasons you need PySPark on Snowflake?

Comment: Because I've used PySpark to execute code on HIVE databases and tables in Apache Spake, and I was hoping I could use the re-use the code execute on snowflake - obviously with some modifications on the code. Is that unrealistic?

Comment: Well, there's no Apache Spark on Snowflake, so from that point of view I do not see why would PySpark be helpful. You have 2 choices: use Spark Connector on the client side or install Snowpark and change the code to match Snowflake format.

Comment: Hi @Sergiu, I did go for the latter suggestion, but there was too much code to change to match snowflake format